# Help with Joins

Tags: sql, join

my first table has about 18K records

so when i

`select * from table2` i get about 18k

i'm trying to do a join on it as follows, but i'm getting like 26K back.. what am i doing wrong? i though it's supposed to return all of the "right" aka table2 records plus show me whatever value matches from the first in a separate column...

```
Select t1.fID , t2.*
FROM table1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.fName = t2.f
```

here is an exmaple of my tables:

table 1:
fID, fName

table 2: id, f, address, etc

i need to get all records from table 2, with an fID column, whenever f=fName

Comment: @Gerrat, i only need the 18K from table 2, with a matching column from table 1 if there is one.

Comment: basically, table 2 has names, table 1 has names and ids, i need to get everything out of table 2, but also have a matching id next to the name.... if there is one

Comment: if the ID's are distinct, you can just do select distinct, otherwise you have to decide WHICH id you want

Comment: i'm so confused :( so there's no way to get all possible ID matches for all names in t2?

Comment: You **are** getting "all possible ID matches for all names in t2"

Comment: i dont want all, i only want matches for the ones that are in table2, with no extras

Comment: Why not switch the order of your tables? Make table1 become table2 and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

table1 has many rows with a value of fname that matches the same in table2.

Example, say 5k rows table2 have no matching rows in table1, you have a average of 2 rows in table 1 for each of the remaining 13k table2 rows

Because you have also asked for a column for table1, this will happen. You'll note multiple t1.fId values for a given t2.fname. Or NULLs

Comment: so, how would i go about getting all records from table 2, with a matching column from table 1, if there is one..

Comment: @xrum...which matching row would you like to display the column from...as gbn explained, there are multiple matching rows.

Comment: @xrum: you are getting this. You can't reduce the rows unless you 1. aggregate and take perhaps the MIN(t1.fId) or 2. decide not to have t1.fId at all

Comment: @Gerrat -  table 2 has names and all kids of other information, table 1 has names and ids, i need to get everything out of table 2, but also have a matching id next to the name.... if there is one

Comment: @xrum: you need a way of matching a row in table 2 to a row in table 1 in addition to the name

Comment: there's nothing else in that table :(

Comment: ok, i found another field i can join the two tables by. but how do i do two joins at the same time??? Select distinct t2.siteID, t1.facilityID ,  t2.*
FROM table1 t1  right outer join table2 t2 on t1.facilityName = t2.facility and
table1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.siteCode = t2.siteID

Answer (score 2):

If t1.fName and t2.f aren't unique identifiers for their tables, you will find that rows from table1 are being joined with multiple rows from table2.

Answer (score 0):

The RIGHT JOIN keyword Return all rows from the right table (table_name2), even if there are no matches in the left table (table_name1).[See Right Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp)

So it looks like you do not have your matching criteria set correctly or you have no matches.

Comment: Because Right join gets all records from the right table regardless of whether or not a match exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible when some fName values are repeated in Table2 and/or Table 1.

Run these Queries and See:

```
SELECT fName, COUNT(1) FROM Table2 GROUP BY fName HAVING COUNT(1) > 1

SELECT fName, COUNT(1) FROM Table1 GROUP BY fName HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: FYI, COUNT(1) adds no benefit... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649

Comment: I don't want to start this again :).. I just follow it as a practice and I don't expect it to be performing better than COUNT(*)